# OpenLayers v3.5.0 map, loading features from a GeoJSON using bbox strategy

Tags: angularjs, openlayers-3

I'm trying to use the approach described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844412/how-to-load-open-layers-3-geojson-vector-layer-with-bbox), but instead of using jQuery to perform the ajax request, I'm using angularJS $http method. I've already verified and the features are being loaded into the source of the layer, but nothing is shown.

Here is the definition of the source:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  loader: function(extent, resolution){   
     $http.get(url).success(function(data){

     var formatGeo = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

     var features = formatGeo.readFeatures(data,
       {featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326'});

    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    console.log(vectorSource.getFeatures().length);
  })},
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});
```

Is there any incompatibility problems with using angularJS and openlayers?

Comment: What is your geojson projection?

Comment: The projection for the geoJSON was 'EPSG:4326'. It was solved when I added the definition  `projection: 'EPSG:3857'` in the View of my map.

Comment: if this is solved, post your answer and finish this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the mismatch of the projection of the data in my GeoJSON (EPSG:4326) and of the map (OpenLayers3 default, EPSG:3857).

To solve the problem, I changed the projection of the data that I was using to build the GeoJSON to EPSG:3857. Since the data was stored in a postGis database, I used the function ST_Transform to change the projection of the geom column contaning the objects.